# Easiest way to make multiple checkboxes in Xamarin? C#/XML

Tags: c#, checkbox, xamarin.android

I need to create 8005 checkboxes in an app on Xamarin.

The app I am making takes thousands of phrases and pastes them into a text box so that the user can edit them.

The way I am going about this is by putting 27 buttons on the first page, one for each letter (an extra for numbers) and after selecting a number it brings you to another page with a checkbox for each phrase. After selecting each phrase that you want, there is a get results button to paste them all into a text editor.

I am having to copy and paste the checkbox code over and over and over, adding a different ID to each checkbox with a different phrase.

This is the code I am using:

```
    <CheckBox
    android:text="Living the American dream "
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used xamarin, but I wonder if it would be better to use a list/datagrid/table where each row is a checkbox - you need only populate a collection with the data you want to display, and configure how the row is to be displayed. Then the checkboxes will be dynamically created. Furthermore, the list/datagrid/table will create a subset of rows  only those that are visible - which will reduce your memory footprint.

Comment: Could you go into a little more detail for me as to how to do that/how it would work? I kind of grasp what you mean, but I'm not 100% sure.
I am relatively new to coding, but I understand it quite well.

Comment: Check out the following links: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/ and http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview's_appearance/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create these many controls then it is better to create it dynamically using code rather then using xml. Just like this :

```
        var checkBoxes = new CheckBox[0];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 8005; i++)
        {
            var checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
            checkBox.Text = "your phrase";
            checkBox.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            parentLayout.AddView(checkBox);

            Array.Resize(ref checkBoxes, i + 1);
            checkBoxes[i] = checkBox;
        }
```

And then you can get CheckBox list which is checked by user on your button click like this :

```
        var selectedCheckBoxes = checkBoxes.Where(c => c.Checked);
```